# Count numer of independent observations in group with repeated meassures

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to count the number of independent observations per group in a group that has repeated measures.

Here's some toy data

```
library(dplyr)
df <- bind_rows(mtcars, mtcars, mtcars) %>%
 mutate(id=rep(row.names(mtcars),3))
```

In this data,

```
df %>% group_by(cyl, id) %>% count()
```

shows

```
# A tibble: 32 x 3
# Groups:   cyl, id [32]
     cyl id                 n
   <dbl> <chr>          <int>
 1     4 Datsun 710         3
 2     4 Fiat 128           3
 3     4 Fiat X1-9          3
 4     4 Honda Civic        3
 5     4 Lotus Europa       3
 6     4 Merc 230           3
 7     4 Merc 240D          3
 8     4 Porsche 914-2      3
 9     4 Toyota Corolla     3
10     4 Toyota Corona      3
# … with 22 more rows
```

This is the number of observations per individual (aka each car). To get the number of independent observations per group (how many cars for each `cyl`) I could do it like this.

```
df %>% group_by(cyl,id) %>% count() %>% ungroup() %>% group_by(cyl) %>% count()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

which gives the correct result (check `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% count()`)

The `group_by(...) %>% count() %>% ungroup() %>% group_by() %>% count()` is not intuitive to me.

**What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?**

**Related question, is there a way to pipe the count into the original df or you need a new object and `left_join(...)`?**

Comment: A bit shorter than your approach would be `df %>% count(cyl,id) %>% count(cyl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `n_distinct()` -

```
df %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarize(n = n_distinct(id))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

For your related question you can do -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(n = n_distinct(id)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Awesome, looks like `n_distinct()` behavior somewhat like what we would expect for `unique(df$id)`, but nested within group thanks to the `group_by()`.

Comment: yes, you can think of it as `length(unique(df$id))` within each group.